# Explode to array and print each element as list item?

Tags: php, explode

I have a set of numbers in a table field in database, the numbers are separated by comma '|1||10||12|'. I am trying to do the following:

```
$array =  explode('|', $set_of_numbers);
```

answer

```
["","1","","10","","12",""]
```

I need so

```
["1","10","12"]
```

as can be done thank you for previously

Comment: [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter)

Comment: "_the numbers are separated by comma '|1||10||12|'_" Looks like they're not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
$array = trim($array, '|');
$array = explode('||', $set_of_numbers);
```

Comment: That works very specifically for this example, but I'm not sure the spec is that there will always be `||` in the middle and `|` and the ends…

Comment: Sure, this is a specific answer. But judging by the question, that's what he will always have in his $set_of_numbers.

Comment: @deceze Wouldn't that also be true for all the other answers?

Comment: @kerbholz No, `array_filter` works regardless of how many `|` there are or in what combination.

Comment: @deceze Oh, ok, I see, I thought you were talking about the seperator being `,` or something. Nevermind ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use this, `array_filter()` function will removes your empty/blank values from array & will return array which has values only.

```
$set_of_numbers = '|1||10||12|';
$array =  array_filter(explode('|', $set_of_numbers));
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this,

```
$set_of_numbers = '|1||10||12|';
$array = array_filter(explode("|", $set_of_numbers), function($value) { return $value!== ''; });
```

It will work you can use this, I tested this on phpfiddle.

Comment: You can simplify that filter to `array_filter(..., 'strlen')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
This will work.

```
$set_of_numbers = '|1||10||12|';
$array =  explode('|', $set_of_numbers);
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expression:

```
<?php

$a = '|1||10||12|';
$matches = [];
preg_match_all('/(\d+)/', $a, $matches);
var_dump($matches[1]);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php